# Create WatchKit PNG Animations

Tags: ios, animation, watchkit

I understand how png animations work, however i'm having a hard time doing them. IS the best way really to open photoshop and draw things one frame at a time?

I want to create a simple circle being drawn, so far I'm to frame 30 of 120, i'm adding shapes every 5 pixels or so, and it is taking forever.

There has to be a better way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the many generator for Radial Chart. Some are in objective-C, other are online like this one : http://hmaidasani.github.io/RadialChartImageGenerator/

I also think there is possibility to automate Photoshop to do stuff like this, but I'm not a Photoshop pro by myself